# Can't get video to download with qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5

I'm trying to download a file using qt

```cpp
        QNetworkAccessManager manager;
        QUrl videoUrl = "https://www.animeunityserver15.cloud/DDL/Anime/SewayakiKitsuneNoSenko-san/SewayakiKitsuneNoSenko-san_Ep_01_SUB_ITA.mp4";
        QNetworkReply* response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(videoUrl));
        QFile file("./video.mp4");
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        file.write(response->readAll());
        file.close();
```

I don't get any error but the file is 0kb meaning that it hasn't been actually downloaded.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you run wget from the command line with the same URL, is it able to download the file?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it does work, I think the problem is that i write to the file before it has actually been downloaded because sometimes it's 5kb, but i have no idea why

Comment: The docs says that QNetworkReply has a signal that is triggered once the complete answer is available, I would try to hook to it and write once you receive the signal https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#finished

Comment: What @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts says: The API is asynchronous, you need to wait for the results. For large files, use readyRead(), to process the data incrementally as it comes in, instead of one huge chunk.

Comment: This tutorial seems a nice starting point: https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QNetworkRequest_Http_File_Download.php and uses the solution that Frank has proposed